# How to inject navigator object before page codes run firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to inject an element to navigator object on browser all tabs/windows before page content loaded. for example:

```
window.navigator.myCustomObject = "this is my data";
```

I found an example but this code is not working with bootstrapped extension how to do same with a bootstrapped extension?

bootstrap.js:

```
function startup(data, reason) {

// some magic here

}
```

I tried copy this code in startup function not worked. I think window. object is not defined here and I didn't find how to do it :(
An example code from firefox-webdriver addon:

```
// This will configure a FirefoxDriver and DomMessenger for each
// _browser window_ (not chrome window). Multiple tabs in the same window will
// share a FirefoxDriver and DomMessenger instance.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  // http://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#security-and-privacy
  var appcontent = document.getElementById('appcontent');
  if (appcontent) {
    appcontent.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
      var doc = e.originalTarget || e.target;
      var isSvg = doc.documentElement.nodeName == 'svg';
      var script = isSvg ?
          doc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'script') :
          doc.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      script.textContent = '(' + function() {
        Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'webdriver', {
          value: true,
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false
        });
      } + ')()';
      doc.documentElement.appendChild(script);
      doc.documentElement.removeChild(script);
    });
  }
});
```

Edit: I found a solution with Addon-SDK:

```
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
let myObserver =
    {
        QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIObserver, Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference]),
        observe: function(subject, topic, data)
        {
            if (topic === "content-document-global-created" && subject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow /*&& subject.location.hostname === "example.com"*/)
            {
                XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject).navigator.webdriver = true;
                XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject).navigator.oglum = function() { return "babacim"; };
            }
        }
    };
let observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(myObserver, "content-document-global-created", true);
```